# Git pushes my branch with different account

Tags: git, version-control, webstorm, git-push, git-remote

When I commit the changes I made, it is committed by my current account. When I push my changes to remote, I see some other account that is used by me before. Commits are okay but push operation seems like made by a different account. Because of that, I can't delete my branch from remote.

I've changed git config the user locally and globally and I've set up the project clearly from scratch. Also, I changed the password of the second account but still pushing with it.
I don't use git bash, I manage git with Webstrom.

Where can I change the account that pushes?

Edit: I've cloned another project from remote but it is still pushing with the unwanted account.

Comment: It sounds like the server is inferring different information based on how you authenticate. Check to make sure that the server you push to is configured with the same email information as your local client.

Comment: Looks like your SSH key is saved in this another account...

Comment: I didn't use ssh key before @MarceloFilho

Comment: I checked and it is same email  @crashmstr